# Calculate power on time of a buzzer

Tags: capacitor, discharge, time, piezo-buzzer

I would like to use a 5v active piezo buzzer to beep for a second or two. When the relay is on NO the capacitor will charge from the dc source and when the relay is on NC the capacitor will discharge through the buzzer until the voltage is too low to supply it. Will something like this work? Does anyone knows how to calculate the power on time?

Thank you to anyone interested!!!

[image: My circuit. The Relay is controlled externally]

Answer (score 1):

The beeper does not draw a constant 25 mA at all voltage levels between 3.5 V and 5.0 V, and we do not know what the actual current draw is (<=25 mA could mean 2 or 22).  So the best we can do now is make some assumptions to at least get a feel for a solution.

Worst case is that the buzzer draws the full 25 mA at all operating voltages, and shuts off at 3.499 V.  In this case, the equation for capacitor voltage during a constant current charge or discharge is

E x C = i x t   >>>   The change in capacitor voltage times the cap value (in farads) equals the constant current (in amperes) times the time the current is applied.

In your case you have a 0.001 F capacitor, a 25 mA current, and a change in capacitor voltage of 1.5 V (5 V down to 3.5 V).  Therefore, the beeper will beep for 0.06 seconds.

This is 40% less than the other calculation.  One reason is that while the total energy in the cap is 12.5 mJ, not all of that energy can be used.  At some voltage between 3.4999 V and 0 V, the beeper will stop beeping because there is not enough voltage headroom to run the internal 1-transistor oscillator.  We do not know what the true minimum operating voltage is, but we know it could be 3.499999 V.

On the other hand, as the operating voltage decreases from 5 V to 3.5 V, the current draw also decreases.  This will increase the operating time to something greater than 0.06 seconds, but we don't know by how much because the current decrease is not perfectly proportional to the voltage decrease.  My guess is that the increase due only to this is in the 10% to 30% range.

AND - If you use the total energy calculation method, you come up with a worse worst case run time of only 0.051 seconds.  But if you calculate the buzzer energy at both the beginning (125 mW) and end (87.5 mW) of a discharge cycle and average the two as an approximation of the total power throughout a cycle (rather than use 125 mW throughout), you get the same answer as before:  0.06 s.

Again, this is a worst case approximation.  The actual time probably will be about twice this.  And if the beeper actually operates down to 2 V or so, the run time will be much longer.

Comment: Another way to look at this is to use the RC time constant, which in this case would be 200 ohms of the resistor and 5/25 = 200 ohms of the buzzer, or 400 ms. However, the series resistor will make the peak buzzer voltage only 2.5 V, so it might not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Will something like this work?

Surely depends on the buzzer. Probably the 200R resistor will limit the current flow so you may not even hear the buzzer.

Why don't you use an NE555 in monostable mode?

[image]

Image source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/555-timer-monostable-circuit/

When you press the button for a short time, the circuit will give a pulse for a duration of \$\mathrm{T_d [ms]=1.1 \ R[kOhm]\ C[\mu F]}\$. For \$\mathrm{T_d=1[s]}\$, \$\mathrm{R=9k1}\$ and \$\mathrm{C=100\mu F}\$ can be used.

There's a handy calculator on that page.

Comment: I will check it out. I didn't think of it. Will something like this work if I remove the resistor?

Comment: @matthewg Still depends on the buzzer. The capacitor will hold an energy of \$\mathrm{W=C\ V^2 / 2} = 12.5mJ\$. How can we know that how long the buzzer can beep with this amount of energy without knowing the technical properties of the buzzer?

Comment: Ohh. I thought that this small 5v piezo buzzer is a standard one so all of them are the same. You are right. I will try to search some technical properties and I will come back. Thank you for your time :D

Comment: the characteristics of the buzzer are:
input voltage: 3,5-5V
Input Current: <=25mA
Frequency: 2300Hz +-500Hz

Comment: @matthewg Thanks for the info. The power consumption of the buzzer is around \$\mathrm{P=5V 25mA=125mW}\$. So, the energy of 12.5mJ can provide the power of 125mW for a duration of \$\mathrm{dt=W/P=12.5/125=0.1 second}\$. For 1 second, you should increase the capacitance to 10000uF. Please note that I neglected the internal losses and the capacitance tolerance of the capacitor. So even if you increase the capacitance to 10mF you may get less than 1 second in practice.

Comment: So a 555 ic is the only solution as it seems

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. None of the comments explained the issue. Another option would be a small microcontroller, which would require fewer components, and probably be cheaper as well as more flexible (programmable).

Comment: @PStechPaul my achievements history shows a -10 points (downvote) because of the user (i.e. the upvoter) was removed.